# How to get the average value of a set of mysql records?

Tags: php

I have a table with a set of fields. Each of these fields contains a number between one and 10.

```
|item_id|field1|field2|field3|field4|
|1      | 2    |5     |2     |9     |
|3      | 9    |3     |5     |10    |
|4      | 9    |9     |9     |10    |
```

What I would like to do is get the average of these fields. However, I need the number to be between 10 and 100.

Comment: Did you try it yourself ? Can we see your code ?

Comment: `SELECT (field1 + field2 + field3 + field4)*10/4 AS average FROM mytbl` Will calculate the average for each row.

Comment: Average for what? Which field? All the fields? Over all the rows? What?

Comment: sooo we should do everything while you are resting in peace huh!

Comment: @JonStirling: for each item_id in row.

Answer (score 0):

First what you wanna do is multiply the rating by 10;

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $rating = 0;
    $rating = $rating + $result['field1']         + $result['field2'] + $result['field3'] + $result['field4'];

    // Multiply rating by 10
    $rating = $rating*10;

    // Devide rating by 4
    $rating = $rating/4;

    // Output average
    echo $result['item_id']." : ".$rating."<br />";
}
```

Or you could do it even simpler while doing your query:

```
SELECT
(field1 + field2 + field3 + field4)*10/4 AS average
FROM table
```